# How to install package with all dependencies offline!

Tags: package-management

I have a Ubuntu Server setup, and it doesn't have internet, so I'm downloading packages from http://packages.ubuntu.com and installing them manually (instead of using `apt-get`).

But the problem is, some of the package dependencies just doesn't install! For instance, the [`build-essential`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/build-essential) package depends on another package which depends on five other packages and so on.

It's going to take me an hour to click all the download links and download all of them.

What should I do?

Comment: you could install the dependencies through gdebi. But it needs an internet connection.

Comment: @AvinashRaj which is exactly what I don't have..... or else I would use apt-get

Comment: @Creator who said I was satisfied?

Comment: @Louie ignore it not for you

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command to list everything a package needs for its installation and then download all of them:

```
$ sudo apt-get --print-uris --yes install <package-name> | grep ^\' | cut -d\' -f2 > downloads.list
```

And read [this](http://www.tuxradar.com/answers/517) if you need more information.

Comment: then from where are you downloading packages??

Comment: This is very useful, but this assumes I have another linux machine with internet. But I really can't ask for more I guess. I'll wait a bit and if there isn't anything beter I'll choose you

Comment: Yes, my question assumes I have another machine with internet, sadly my other machine does not run linux, but I guess you're answer is pretty good already, I'll install linux on my other machine just to run this line.....

Comment: doesn't work on 16.04, `grep: invalid argument ' for '--directories'`